# how could I using query-replace like isearch-forward while typing something

Tags: emacs, elisp

while isearch-forward run as a command, the context I had typed will hightlight in the current buffer, but while run query-replace don't hightlight that, how can i make it hightlight?

Comment: You can try [anzu](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-anzu/) or [visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el/), I'm using the former, it not also highlights matched string, but also previews replaced string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `isearch-query-replace`. It highlights the string to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

1. It sounds like you are saying that `query-replace` does not highlight all of the matching occurrences.  Is that right?  It **should** highlight them.  If it does not, then try starting Emacs without your init file: `emacs -Q`.  If that shows no lack of highlighting then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.
2. @Rocky mentioned `isearch-query-replace`.  That doesn't change highlighting (which should already be turned on), but what it does do is let you start query-replacing while you are isearching, using the last search string as the pattern for the text to be matched by `query-replace`.
3. An alternative to query-replace, useful especially if you have relatively few replacements you want to make and there are lots of matches, is to use [*on-demand replacement*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-replace-on-demand) while isearching.  For that you need library [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus).

   To replace any given search hit on demand, just hit **`C-M-RET`**.  With a prefix arg, `C-M-RET` prompts you for the replacement text (the default is to replace with no text, which means to delete the hit).  You can thus *change the replacement text anytime*, within the same Isearch invocation.

   After replacing the search hit, `C-M-RET` moves to the next one.  So you can just use it repeatedly if you want to replace several successive search hits.  Or use `C-s` to skip replacing the current hit and move to the next one.

   On-demand Isearch replacement works also for regexp searching, and just as for query-replacing, the replacement text can be either inserted literally, as is, or interpreted as in `query-replace-regexp`. In the latter case, you can use `\&`, `\=\N`, `\#`, `\,` and `\?`. You can use **`` C-M-` ``** anytime during Isearch to toggle whether replacement text is used literally or interpreted per the special regexp-replacement constructs.

Comment: I mean while I typing the pattern text which will be replaced later, query-replace don't hightlight the matching occurrences, it just hightlight the matching after the replaced text and replace text both input and an "Enter" typed.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Yes, query-replace doesn't highlight the search hits until you have entered both search and replacement patterns. Consider filing an enhancement request for it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. But both Isearch followed by `M-%` (`isearch-query-replace`) and Isearch+ replacement-on-demand (`C-M-RET`) show you matches from the outset, and incrementally as you type.

Comment: Yes, Isearch followed by isearch-query-replace do this, but for query-replace-regexp that not work. Thanks a lot, i'll report a bug later.

Comment: Regexp Isearch followed by `M-%` works for me. Consider showing an example (in your question) of what you feel does not work wrt `query-replace-regexp` initiated from isearch.

Comment: Regexp Isearch followed by isearch-query-replace-regexp works right. But the cursor not jump to the next hightlight matching while input 'N', it just jump to next char as 'forward-char' do. I'm using "GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)\n of 2014-10-25 on LEG570".

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are saying. Try to give a step-by-step description in the question itself. Step-by-step means mention each key you  hit etc. Anyway, if the behavior you see is not what you think is appropriated, consider filing a bug report, as I mentioned.

Comment: for example, I want seach "[A-Z]?[a-z]*" in buffer BB

Comment: What part of "*Try to give a step-by-step description in the question itself*" is not clear? Again, sorry, but I do not know what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry, for example, I want seach "[A-Z]?[a-z]*" in buffer BB, BB content is "Name: test" , then I run "query-replace-regexp", then ask me input some pattern in mini-buffer, I input "[A-Z]?", the input is not completed, "N" should be hightlight. But it not hightlight until I input an "Enter" in mini-buffer, and that's too later, because maybe I have input wrong pattern already.

Comment: So you want to see matches for the regexp you type before you hit `RET` to enter it. You said that in the beginning - go back to my first comment. File an enhancement request, if you like. Or use Isearch+'s replacement on demand. Or just repeat query-replace, retrieve the last regexp with `M-p`, and edit it. Or use `C-x ESC ESC` to repeat the whole command, and edit both regexp and replacement. The point is that, as you noted, query-replace does not work the way you want it to work. Either use something else or ask Emacs Dev to enhance query-replace the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

The following packages provide live highlighting and replacement previewing for query replacing, as well as additional features:

- https://github.com/syohex/emacs-anzu
- https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el
- https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el

I currently use `visual-regexp-steroids.el`.

All three packages can be installed from [MELPA](http://melpa.org/).